# Set console width while redirecting the output

Tags: windows-7, command-line, console, redirection

I'm trying to avoid wrapping long lines in the [NetUsers](http://www.systemtools.com/free.htm) output, and the output is ok using a `cmd` window or `Console2` with 200 cols.

However, if I'm redirecting the output to a file, the output is using the standard width of 80 cols.

Is it possible to set a custom width while redirecting the output to a file?

---

For the record, under cygwin the custom console size is ignored.

Also, batch files with `mode 200,60` or similar are having no positive effect.